# Query $or in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

how do I query $or in express.js app.get() function?
For find() query in this example,

```
db.inventory.find( { $or: [ { quantity: { $lt: 20 } }, { price: 10 } ] } )
```

I wonder how can I transform into app.get() function format:

```
app.get('/:collection', function(req,res){
 var collection = db.get(req.param.collection);
 collection.find({}) // Query Part

});
```

Reference:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

Answer (score 0):

With  mongoose mongo driver on top of express, you can do this,

```
app.get('/:collection', function(req,res){
  //var collection = db.get(req.param.collection);
  Collection.find( { $or:[ {'quantity':{ $lt: 20 }}, { price: 10 } ]}, 
      function(err,docs){
        if(!err) res.send(docs);
    });
});
```

Comment: i am confused, what role the route param :collection plays in your soln. in my answer, Collection is got through mongoose DB Connection API